# Error: Can't drop privilege as nonroot user: container keeps restarting on Google Cloud Compute Engine

Tags: php, docker, nginx, google-compute-engine, alpine-linux

I've searched and can't seem to find the answer to this error. "Error: Can't drop privilege as nonroot user" when I create a new VM.

The container keeps restarting. It works just fine on my local MacOS machine.

I'm trying to run the image on a Google Compute Engine VM with the Container Optimized OS.
I'm using nginx, php-fpm, and alpine.

The supervisord.conf file looks like this:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
logfile=/dev/null
logfile_maxbytes=0
pidfile=/run/supervisord.pid
user=root

[program:php-fpm]
command=php-fpm8 -F
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
autostart=true
autorestart=true
priority=5
stdout_events_enabled=true
stderr_events_enabled=true

[program:nginx]
command=nginx -g 'daemon off;'
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
autorestart=false
startretries=0
```

Anyone bumped into this error too?

Answer (score 7):

This looks like you're trying to start Supervisor as a non-root.

Your config file tells the Supervisor to run as root but if you start it as a non-root user then it can't start processes with root privileges. [It was changed](https://pypi.org/project/supervisor/) in 3.3.4 version due to security reasons:

> Fixed a bug where supervisord would continue starting up if the [supervisord] section of the config file specified user= but setuid() to that user failed. It will now exit immediately if it cannot drop privileges.

Have a look at [this duscussion](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/1218);

> You can remove `user=root` entirely, which will allow supervisord to start as root or non-root. When run as root, this has the side effect of printing a warning message to the log, since we recommend having a user= when run as root. Assuming the environment that supervisord is started in contains the variable `USER` and it is set to the current user, you should be able to use `user=%(ENV_USER)s` to run as either user.

Another simillar issue was [discussed at Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/272820/545593).

Comment: I removed user=root and that solved the issue. Thx!